# How can I pass additional parameters to a resource route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Post`.  In `config/routes.rb`, I defined its route as:

```
resources :post
```

Everything works fine with the default paths.  I can create a new post at the following url:

```
/posts/new
```

I need to pass additional parameters so that the new url becomes:

```
/posts/new/:year/:month/:day
```

If I do the following, it assumes a `post_id` should exists:

```
resources :posts do
  match '/new/:year/:month/:day',         
    :to => 'posts#new',
    :constraints => {:year => /\d{4}/, :month => /\d{2}/, :day => /\d{2}/},
    :as => 'new_post'
end
```

For the above, `rake routes` give me:

```
/posts/:post_id/new/:year/:month/:day(.:format)
```

How can I configure the default `new` path to pass additional parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
match '/new/:year/:month/:day', :on => :new
...
```